# GPUImageMovie playback controls

Tags: iphone, avplayer, gpuimage

I'm trying to control the playback of a GPUImageMovie.
What I would like to archive is jump from a frame to another (seekToTime back and forward, swipe controlled) rather then play the video, but I don't understand if the component it's designed for this use.

GPUImageMovie -> filters -> GPUImageView

I've tried to use an AVPlayer on playerItem, but apparetly it's null.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `AVPlayer` for control video: create `GPUImageMovie` by using `AVPlayerItem`, so you can control your video by using `AVPlayer` methods.

example:

```
NSURL *mediaURL = ...
AVPlayer *mainPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:mediaUrl];
[mainPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

GPUImageMovie *currentMovieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[currentMovieFile addTarget:...];
[currentMovieFile startProcessing];
```