# GPUImageMovie set movie play start time

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage

I am converting a movie, using GPUImage.

How can I set play head to the time 15s and end time to 20s in GPUImageMovie?

There is nothing like startTime or endTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to using this answer for implementing video controll.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21782945/1256451